# How can I tell if someone has connected to my machine remotely?

Tags: networking, security, remote, access-control

One thing I have found very disappointing in computing is the lack of notification when someone connects to your computer.  I do a lot of remote work and when I connect to anothers machine they get no notification.  Is there a way in LINUX to get notification if anyone connects remotely to my machine?

Comment: Worth revising question to say whether interested in any one particular protocol (ssh, X11, vnc, telnet, ftp, http, rdp) or the whole lot ?   And also on which particular distro/version of Linux you're wanting to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

**short answer** : there are too many connections.

**long answer**:

You connect to a Linux host in multiple ways: `telnet` & `rlogin` (in the old time), `ssh`, `sftp`, `ftp`, `ftps`, X11 remote , `rdp` , `mysql` , `http` , `vnc`, ...

Some protocols are called 'interactive' (ssh,vnc) while other less (mysql).

Some use "unix" credentials(`/etc/passwd` & `/etc/shadow`) and log files(`/var/log/messages`) : ssh/ftp.

Some have their own (mysql (access and password in database), vnc (private password file)).

On many production systems I work with, you do not use named accounts (e.g. archemar), you use a set of standard accounts (root, SIDadm for SAP system), this makes it next to impossible to know which human being log in the system. (And, yes this is a problem)

Furthermore, those production system exchange between 1 and 100 files per minute, each traced in some log file using unix or specific credential. Parsing log files  is a boring task, and is done mostly **after** a system crash, or more rarely upon a audit.

You may however, try to parse `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/secure` to know if a human being, with proper plain unix id (!= 0 ) log into your system.

You may also  use `last` and `who` command.

Comment: The `w` command is also an option.